# Why do I not see Configure Distribution when I right-click on replication?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I'm using SSMS 2014 for SQL Server 2008 R2.

Why don't I see 'configure distribution' when I right-click on Replication?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the distribution and publication wasn't correctly disabled. When I tried to run the disable the publishing and Distribution (as seen in my image above) I was getting an error that the process couldn't complete because the distribution database was still in use. so I used

```
SELECT spid FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE dbid = db_id('distribution')
```

to find the spid that was using it and then used

```
KILL <the spid>
```

I was then able to fully disable the publishing and Distribution and now I do see the configure distribution option.
[image]